# The truth table

Tags: logic, arithmetic

Considering the proposition: "95.7% of Fake News is disseminated through WhatsApp, and 3 out of 4 people accessing this news are from the Southeast and Northeast." According to logic, one can say:

1. 3 out of 4 people accessing this news are from the Southeast and
   Northeast regions or 95.7% of Fake News are disseminated through
   WhatsApp.
2. 3 out of 4 people who do not access this news are from the Southeast
   and Northeast regions or 95.7% of Fake News are not disseminated through WhatsApp.
3. 95.7% of Fake News is not disseminated through WhatsApp or 3 out of 4 people accessing this news are not from the Southeast and
   Northeast.
4. 95.7% of Fake News is disseminated through WhatsApp and 3 out of 4 people who access this news are not from the Southeast and
   Northeast.
5. 95.7% of Fake News is not disseminated through WhatsApp and 3 out of 4 people accessing this news are from the Southeast and Northeast.

Answer: 01).

I made the table of all except 02) because the first statement does not seem correctly denied, and none works.

Comment: Which "or" is intended here?  Do you mean the "Exclusive or" or the "Inclusive or"?

Comment: @lulu I didn't understand .... I meant it's one of two possibilities

Comment: The Exclusive or means "either one or the other but not both".  The Inclusive or means "either one or the other or both".  It's an important distinction.  I;m guessing whoever set this problem meant the Inclusive or, in which case $\#1$ is correct.

Comment: @lulu  Inclusive or

Comment: Well, then, $\#1$ is correct.

Comment: @lulu Have to justify all?

Comment: It's obvious.  $A$ and $B$ together certainly implies $A$ or $B$, if "or" is meant inclusively.